# Execute Thrift from ant within pom.xml

Tags: macos, maven, thrift

I have some problems running thrift from ant inside a pom.xml. So I have something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <exec executable="thrift">
                        <arg value="--help" />
                    </exec>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And all I get is

```
An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "thrift": error=2, No such file or directory
```

If I try another commands like sh or ls it works just fine. Whats the problem with thrift? It is on my $PATH and I can execute it manually without any problems. I am running this on a Max with OS X 10.7.5 within eclipse Juno and the Maven plugin. Would be greatful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thrift` is not found because it is not in the `$PATH` in the environment you are running.

Since you are running within Eclipse, the `$PATH` taken into account is the one which has also been set to Eclipse itself. Eclipse being generally launched from a Desktop icon, it is then the environment of the 'Desktop', desktop which has been launch by the system, not your bash prompt where you might have changed the default `$PATH`

Several solutions then:

- use an absolute path to the `thrift` tool
- I don't know the Maven launcher in Eclipse, but maybe you can alter the `PATH` environment variable there
- make a symbolic link from /usr/bin:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /the/full/path/of/thrift /usr/bin/thrift
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you maybe explain you one can get eclipse to use additiona path variables because I added the location of my thrift binary in the eclipse settings unter general -> workspace -> linked resources but it showed no effect. However, the absolut link directly in the pom.xml worked.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the Maven plugin. For instance, in a launch configuration of an Ant build, there is the tab 'Environment' where a `PATH` could be set. I guess there should be something similar for Maven.